# Convert char array to void * pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, void

I want to read an address ( Like 0x827483 ) from input, and save this address in a void * variable.
first i make this address as long long variable:

```
while(c != ' ' && !feof(file))
{
    if('0' <= c && c <= '9')
        num = c - '0';
    else if('a' <= c && c <= 'f')
        num = c - 'a' + 10;
    b = b * 16 + num;
    c = fgetc(file);
    s[i++] = c;
}
```

and then i cast it to void *.

```
void * adr = (void *) b;
```

my code is working, but i got warning.

What can i do?

Comment: What is the warning you're getting?

Comment: Converting integers to pointers is not portable, and is often due to an error (forgetting to use `&` to take the address of the variable). That's why compilers warn about it.

Comment: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

Comment: Is there any other solution to read a void * variable from input?

Comment: Make `num` a `char*` to hide the warning. In C++ there's an `int_ptr` type that is made for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is telling you the `long long` integer and the `void *` are different sizes. Most likely, the `long long` is 64 bit while the `void *` is 32 bit.

If you only need to build 32 bit code then you can use `void * adr = (void *)(long)b`.

I think a better solution is to use [`uintptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) instead of `long long`. That will insure the sizes are compatible for both 32 and 64 bit code.

---

As a side note, reading a memory address from a file is an insecure and dangerous practice. You need to validate that the pointer is something useful before you use it in any way.

Comment: sry, i'm new in stack over flow.